# jQuery remember option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have created an option that by clicking on span text shows or hides the sidebar. how to remember user selection after reloading page that the sidebar page was shown or hidden depending on the user's choice?

Comment: As the Cookie Monster would say, Cookies...

Comment: ...or localStorage

Comment: Or server side storage

Answer (score 1):

Once you refresh the page, everything that is not stored somewhere, for example a database, will be lost.

The easiest approach would be to save user's selection to his browser's localStorage.

So, after setting the sidebar to whatever state you want, you can save it like this:

```
localStorage.setItem('showSidebar', true); // or false
```

and then, when the page is reloaded, you can get the data like this:

```js
var showSidebar = localStorage.getItem('showSidebar') || false;
```